# Graphics2D not rendering in iText

Tags: itext, graphics2d

I have an application that needs to mark up existing PDF documents with graphics.  I am trying to use iText and, for the most part, it works.  However i'm having issues with PDF documents that do no have their page rectangle or crop rectangle based at [0, 0].  Here's an abridged version of my code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i + 1);
    PdfCopy.PageStamp stamper = writer.createPageStamp(page);
    PdfContentByte cb = stamper.getOverContent();
    Rectangle cropRect = reader.getCropBox(i + 1);
    Rectangle pageRect = reader.getPageSize(i + 1);

    // construct the transform to place the crop rect of the original PDF into the new PDF
    // This transform is what places the original image content accurately on the page
    // construct a graphics2D object with the proper size (width, height of PDF in question)
    Graphics2D g = cb.createGraphics(2449, 1576);
    cb.saveState();

    // Crop Rectangle coordinates of PDF in question: [0, 24824]
    g.setTransform(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(cropRect.getLeft(), cropRect.getBottom()));

    cb.restoreState();
    g.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 48));
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.drawString("Hello World", 1200, 800);
    g.dispose();

    stamper.alterContents();
    writer.addPage(page);
}
```

In the comments, i specified the size and position of the crop rectangle (which is also the same as the page rectangle).  Also, the application is not drawing "Hello World", rather the Graphics2D object is getting passed to a Swing panel's paint method.

Thanks in advance.